# Pg_featureserv + Mapbox GL JS to display selected results

Tags: jquery, postgresql, postgis, mapbox-gl-js

The problem at hand involves using the [pg_featureserv project](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_featureserv) in conjunction with Mapbox GL JS to display a selected feature on a map. The code appears to be functioning correctly, with search results being displayed in a dropdown list and the Flytofeature function successfully displaying the feature's position. However, the feature geometry is not appearing on the map itself.

I tried following code:

```
var myLayer = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": []
        };

$( function() {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                    var url = "http://localhost:9000/functions/postgisftw.address_query/items.json?partialstr=";
                    var q = encodeURI(request.term);
                    $.get(url+q, function(data) {
                        response(data.features.map(function(d) {
                            return {
                                "value": d["properties"]["value"],
                                "geom": d["geometry"]
                            }
                        }));
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    myLayer.features = [ui.item];
                    map.fitBounds(turf.bbox(ui.item.geom));
                }
            });
        });
  
map.on('load', function() {
            map.addSource('myLayer', {
                "type": "geojson",
                "data": myLayer
            });
map.addLayer({
        'id': 'parcel',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'myLayer',
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': '#0080ff',
            'fill-opacity': 0.5
                }
            });
map.addLayer({
        'id': 'outline',
        'type' : 'line',
        'source' : 'myLayer',
        'layout' : {},
        'paint': {
        'line-color':'#000'
            }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change:

```json
"geom": d["geometry"]
```

To:

```json
"geometry": d["geometry"]
```

The rest of the code is ok.